# Wrapping \cmidrule in a macro

Tags: booktabs, xparse

In my earlier solution for [Multivariate polynomial long division using LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/50404/multivariate-polynomial-long-division-using-latex) I had wrapped `\cmidrule` in a macro as its syntax alowing to shorten the end points was not standard:

```
\newcommand*{\CMidRule}[3]{\cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#1}r{#2}){#3}}%
```

I wanted to use [`xparse`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to to allow for the two shift parameters to be optional, but then ran into problems.

1. Using this only **once** per line works just fine as illustrated in the above linked question.  However, an attempt to use this for two separate `\cmidrule` is problematic in that a vertical shift is produced between subsequent uses (as illustrated in the third table below).

   [image]
2. Furthermore my attempt to use `\NewDocumentCommand` from [the `xparse` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xparse) to allow for two optional parameters does not even compile (hence have commented out the line in the fourth table).  The error message is:

   > ```
   > Misplaced \noalign.
   > \cmidrule ->\noalign 
   >                     {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \@ifnextchar [{\@cmidrule }{\@cmidrule ...
   >  l.40 \CMidRuleX{0.0ex}
   >                        {0.0ex}{1-1}\CMidRuleX{0.0ex}{0.0ex}{2-2}
   > ```

### References:

- [How to make a \cline or \cmidrule narrower?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18691/how-to-make-a-cline-or-cmidrule-narrower)

### Question:

- How do I properly define `\NewDocumentCommand{\CMidRuleX}{O{0.0ex} O{0.0ex} m}{}`?

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xparse}

\newcommand*{\CMidRule}[3]{\cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#1}r{#2}){#3}}%

\NewDocumentCommand{\CMidRuleX}{%
    O{0.0ex}% #1 = left adjust
    O{0.0ex}% #1 = right adjust
    m%   #3 = columns to span
    }{%
    \cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#1}r{#2}){#3}%
}%


\begin{document}
\section*{Direct use of cmidrule works just fine}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
  Left & Right \\
  \cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-2}
    2  &   3   \\
\end{tabular}
\hspace{1.0cm}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
  Left & Right \\
  \cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{0.0ex}r{0.5ex}){1-1}\cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{0.5ex}r{0.0ex}){2-2}
    2  &   3   \\
\end{tabular}
%
\bigskip
\section*{Wrapping cdmidrule in a macro does not work}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
  Left & Right \\
  \CMidRule{0.0ex}{0.5ex}{1-1}\CMidRule{0.5ex}{0.0ex}{2-2}
    2  &   3   \\
\end{tabular}
\hspace{1.0cm}
\begin{tabular}{rc}
  Left & Right \\
  %\CMidRuleX[0.0ex][0.0ex]{1-1}\CMidRuleX[0.0ex][0.0ex]{2-2}
    2  &   3   \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: On the fact that the two rules fail to align, you can see that there is a look-ahead in operation if you simply place the code you have inside a simple macro (`\def\test{\cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{0.5ex}r{0.0ex}){2-2}}`). This will fail to line up, even though it 'should', as the first `\cmidrule` does not 'look' for a hidden following one.

Comment: Related Question: [What is wrong with this TeX macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79848/what-is-wrong-with-this-tex-macro).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In tables, the material which is inserted between rows, for instance rules, is added using the TeX primitive `\noalign`.  Namely, a simplistic definition for `\hline` could be `\noalign{\hrule}`: "insert a horizontal rule (`\hrule`) independently of the current alignment".  This `\noalign` should appear immediately after the `\cr` primitive, used inside `\\`, which ends a line.

As I explained in a recent answer about [how and why TeX looks for `\noalign`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63368/2707), TeX searches for `\noalign` after each `\cr` by expanding recursively the first token which follows `\cr`.  It stops at any non-expandable token or any protected macro.

The issue is that in your case, TeX does not try hard enough, and fails to find the `\noalign` hidden in `\CMidRuleX`.  In fact, looking for optional arguments robustly is not expandable, it requires assignments, and macros such as `\hrule` or `\cmidrule` have to play tricks on TeX to succeed in taking optional arguments.

First option in your case: use `\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand` to create an expandable command.  Searching for optional arguments will not be quite robust anymore, but it should be fine since your macro ends with a mandatory argument.

```
\DeclareExpandableDocumentCommand{\CMidRuleX}{%
    O{0.0ex}% #1 = left adjust
    O{0.0ex}% #1 = right adjust
    m%   #3 = columns to span
}{%
    \cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#1}r{#2}){#3}%
}%
```

Second option: play some tricks on TeX.  Start with `\noalign\bgroup` to enter the no-alignment world, then look for optional arguments.  After the optional arguments are found, end your `\noalign` group with `\egroup`, and insert the `\cmidrule` business.

```
\newcommand{\CMidRuleY}{\noalign\bgroup\CMidRuleYaux}
\NewDocumentCommand{\CMidRuleYaux}{%
    O{0.0ex}% #1 = left adjust
    O{0.0ex}% #1 = right adjust
    m%   #3 = columns to span
}{%
    \egroup
    \cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#1}r{#2}){#3}%
}%
```

Neither of those solutions solves the issue that two `\cmidrule` in a row fail to align.  The only way for those to align is that the first `\cmidrule` must know that it is followed by another `\cmidrule`.  Since we are hiding `\cmidrule` in macros, we must check for further `\cmidrule` ourselves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse, booktabs}
\newcommand{\CMidRuleZ}{\noalign\bgroup\CMidRuleZaux{}}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\CMidRuleZaux}{
    m % Material to reinsert before cmidrule.
    O{0.0ex} % #1 = left adjust
    O{0.0ex} % #1 = right adjust
    m  %   #3 = columns to span
}{
    \peek_meaning_remove_ignore_spaces:NTF \CMidRuleZ
      { \CMidRuleZaux { #1 \cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#2}r{#3}){#4} } }
      { \egroup #1 \cmidrule[\cmidrulewidth](l{#2}r{#3}){#4} }
}
\makeatother
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccc}
  a & b & c & d & e & f & g & h \\
  \CMidRuleZ{1-2}
  \CMidRuleZ{4-5}
  \CMidRuleZ{7-8}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

EDIT: changed the approach to collect all `\CMidRuleZ` first, then call the `\cmidrule` consecutively.

Comment: This works fine if only one `\CMidRuleZ` is used: `\CMidRuleZ[0.0ex][0.0ex]{1-1}` (although the table appears to be vertically shifted down). But, when I try to use it twice `\CMidRuleZ[0.0ex][0.0ex]{1-1}\CMidRuleZ[0.0ex][0.0ex]{2-2}` I get `Missing } inserted.`.  Does this perhaps require TeXLive2012?

Comment: @PeterGrill No, the code was just completely wrong.