# tabucline with a break

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, tabu

In the following the first two columns are different in nature from the last two and I wanted to emphasize this by having a break in the horizontal line.  I drew lines across columns 1 and 2 and then across 3 and 4 but they connect up.  How can I get some space between them so that there are two distinct horizontal line segments?  If possible I would like to stick with using tabu.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu}{XXXX}
1 & 2 & a & b\\
\tabucline{1-2 3-4}
1 & 2 & a & b\\
\end{tabu}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Output (ok except I would like some space in the horizontal line between column 2 and 3):

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `\cmidrule` from the `booktabs` package which provides a method of shortening each end:

[image]

### Notes:

- Since the syntax of this command is not quite standard I would recommend wrapping that in a macro as per [Wrapping \cmidrule in a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63355/wrapping-cmidrule-in-a-macro).

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabu}{XXXX}
1 & 2 & a & b\\
\cmidrule(r{1.0ex}){1-2}\cmidrule(l{1.0ex}){3-4}
1 & 2 & a & b\\
\end{tabu}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I should have included the fact that the rule is in color since that was part of my `\tabucline` command before I made the example minimal but it seems that `\arrayrulecolor{red}` placed before the `cmidrule` line does work so I am ok after all.

Comment: Is there a solution that does not require booktabs?  In another question it was pointed out in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64332/vertical-space-around-horizontal-rules-between-tabu-rows-while-maintaining-color that there is a problem with using booktabs with tables having color.

Comment: @user1189687: I do not know, but I am not an expert on tables by any means...