# divide table cells by a certain amount

Tags: tables, calculations

I made a mistake in the values that i put in the table. I need to divide all the values by 105. Is there a method where i can do it without having to replace this with a completely new table ?

```
 % Table generated by Excel2LaTeX from sheet 'Sheet1'
    \begin{table}[htbp]
      \centering
      \caption{Add caption}
        \begin{tabular}{rrrr}
        \toprule
              & A     & B     & C \\
        \midrule
        1     & 122   & 133   & 156 \\
        2     & 112   & 135   & 155 \\
        3     & 150   & 139   & 158 \\
        4     & 145   & 135   & 159 \\
        5     & 150   & 130   & 200 \\
        \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}%
      \label{tab:addlabel}%
    \end{table}%
```

Comment: With the dividers or separators inherent to `tabular`, you can copy-and-paste the result into a spreadsheet package (like Excel), perform the operation and paste it back into TeX... Is this a possibility?

Comment: Related Question: [spreadtab insert multiple values to a cell](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65306/spreadtab-insert-multiple-values-to-a-cell).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`spreadtab`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab) package; a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\newcommand\Factor{105}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}
\nprounddigits{3}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rrrr}}
\toprule
               & @A              & @B            & @C         \\
\midrule
        @1     & 122/\Factor   & 133/\Factor   & 156/\Factor \\
        @2     & 112/\Factor   & 135/\Factor   & 155/\Factor \\
        @3     & 150/\Factor   & 139/\Factor   & 158/\Factor \\
        @4     & 145/\Factor   & 135/\Factor   & 159/\Factor \\
        @5     & 150/\Factor   & 130/\Factor   & 200/\Factor \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And using `\STcopy` the job is simpler; we built with one instruction a new table with the results of the divisions and hide the original values:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\newcommand\Factor{105}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}
\nprounddigits{3}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rrrrrrr}}
\toprule
 & \SThidecol @A & \SThidecol @B & \SThidecol @C & @A & @B & @C \\
\midrule
@1 & 122 & 133 & 156 & \STcopy{>3,v4}{b2/\Factor} &  & \\
@2 & 112 & 135 & 155 & & & \\
@3 & 150 & 139 & 158 & & & \\
@4 & 145 & 135 & 159 & & & \\
@5 & 150 & 130 & 200 & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: isnt it possible to define a global variable on top so that in case i need to change the amount i divide, i only have to change one global variable ?

Comment: @user581544 I've updated my answer with an improved version of the code.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this **without** changing the data entries by using [the `collcell`  package](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/collcell).

Below I have defined the `R` column type which divides the number by the value specified in `\Factor`, and prints the number using `\pgfmathprintnumber` which allows for formatting the number.  The options `[precision=3]` have been applied to only print three decimal digits.  The table on the left is using the `r` column type, and the one on the right is using the `R` column type.

[image]

### Notes:

- Below I have used toggles from the `etoolbox`, but the same functionality can be achieved with other approaches as in [Conditional typesetting / build](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33576/conditional-typesetting-build/).

---

### Manually Specify end of Header:

This version require one to add `\StartingHeader` at the start of the header (which disables the application of the factor to the data entry), and `\DoneWithHeader` at the end of the header so that subsequent data values are divided by `\Factor`.  Automated version is below.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\Factor}{105}%
\newcommand{\FactorCell}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ComputedValue}{#1/\Factor}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[,fixed,precision=3]{\ComputedValue}%
    }{%
        #1% Still working on header
    }%
}%
\newtoggle{DoneWithHeader}%
\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}%
\newcommand*{\StartingHeader}{\global\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}}%
\newcommand*{\DoneWithHeader}{\global\toggletrue{DoneWithHeader}}%

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\FactorCell}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
              & A     & B     & C \\
    \midrule
    1     & 122   & 133   & 156 \\
    2     & 112   & 135   & 155 \\
    3     & 150   & 139   & 158 \\
    4     & 145   & 135   & 159 \\
    5     & 150   & 130   & 200 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{2.0ex}
\begin{tabular}{rRRR}
    \toprule\StartingHeader
              & A     & B     & C \\
    \midrule\DoneWithHeader
    1     & 122   & 133   & 156 \\
    2     & 112   & 135   & 155 \\
    3     & 150   & 139   & 158 \\
    4     & 145   & 135   & 159 \\
    5     & 150   & 130   & 200 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```

---

### Automated Method:

If you will always have a `\toprule` before the header row, and a `\midrule` prior to the data entries, you can automate the setting of `\StartingHeader` and `\DoneWithHeader`. With this version, the only change required is switching the data column type form `r` to `R`.

The MWE below produces output identical to the above.

### References:

- I needed to add `\noexpand` in the redefinition of `\toprule` and `\midrule`. See [Wrapping \cmidrule in a macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63355/wrapping-cmidrule-in-a-macro) for more details.  It seems that `\toprule` and `\midrule` have a similar issue.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcommand{\Factor}{105}%
\newcommand{\FactorCell}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ComputedValue}{#1/\Factor}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\ComputedValue}%
    }{%
        #1% Still working on header
    }%
}%
\newtoggle{DoneWithHeader}%
\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}%
\newcommand*{\StartingHeader}{\global\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}}%
\newcommand*{\DoneWithHeader}{\global\toggletrue{DoneWithHeader}}%

\LetLtxMacro\OldTopRule\toprule
\def\toprule{\StartingHeader\noexpand\OldTopRule}

\LetLtxMacro\OldMidRule\midrule
\def\midrule{\DoneWithHeader\noexpand\OldMidRule}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\FactorCell}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
              & A     & B     & C \\
    \midrule
    1     & 122   & 133   & 156 \\
    2     & 112   & 135   & 155 \\
    3     & 150   & 139   & 158 \\
    4     & 145   & 135   & 159 \\
    5     & 150   & 130   & 200 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{2.0ex}
\begin{tabular}{rRRR}
    \toprule
              & A     & B     & C \\
    \midrule
    1     & 122   & 133   & 156 \\
    2     & 112   & 135   & 155 \\
    3     & 150   & 139   & 158 \\
    4     & 145   & 135   & 159 \\
    5     & 150   & 130   & 200 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```