# spreadtab insert multiple values to a cell

Tags: tables

```
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rrrr}}
\toprule
               & @A              & @B            & @C         \\
\midrule
        1     & 33 122   & 133/\Factor   & 156/\Factor \\
        2     & 66 112   & 135/\Factor   & 155/\Factor \\
        3     & 77 150   & 139/\Factor   & 158/\Factor \\
        4     & 55 145   & 135/\Factor   & 159/\Factor \\
        5     & 44 150   & 130/\Factor   & 200/\Factor \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}
```

I receive this error

FP Evaluation results in multiple values!

Is there a trick that i can use to insert multiple values ?

Comment: Can you please explain why do you want to have multiple values in one cell? A description of your goal could be useful.

Comment: i need to display feature numbers selected by feature selection algorithm on one column. and the amount of features can vary

Comment: Related Question: [divide table cells by a certain amount](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65302/divide-table-cells-by-a-certain-amount/65311#65311).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you need, but you can treat those values as text entries:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{spreadtab}

\newcommand\Factor{105}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand\STprintnum[1]{\numprint{#1}}
\nprounddigits{3}
\begin{spreadtab}{{tabular}{rrrr}}
\toprule
               & @A              & @B            & @C         \\
\midrule
        1     & @33 122   & 133/\Factor   & 156/\Factor \\
        2     & @66 112   & 135/\Factor   & 155/\Factor \\
        3     & @77 150   & 139/\Factor   & 158/\Factor \\
        4     & @55 145   & 135/\Factor   & 159/\Factor \\
        5     & @44 150   & 130/\Factor   & 200/\Factor \\
\bottomrule
\end{spreadtab}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also adapt the solutions form [divide table cells by a certain amount](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65302/divide-table-cells-by-a-certain-amount/65311#65311) for this case. Here is the automated version which uses the `r` column type for the column where you don't want the factor applied and the `R` column type to apply the factor. The first table here uses `{rrrr}` and the second table uses `{rrRR}` columns.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{collcell}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\newcommand{\Factor}{105}%
\newcommand{\FactorCell}[1]{%
    \iftoggle{DoneWithHeader}{%
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\ComputedValue}{#1/\Factor}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber[precision=3]{\ComputedValue}%
    }{%
        #1% Still working on header
    }%
}%
\newtoggle{DoneWithHeader}%
\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}%
\newcommand*{\StartingHeader}{\global\togglefalse{DoneWithHeader}}%
\newcommand*{\DoneWithHeader}{\global\toggletrue{DoneWithHeader}}%

\LetLtxMacro\OldTopRule\toprule
\def\toprule{\StartingHeader\noexpand\OldTopRule}

\LetLtxMacro\OldMidRule\midrule
\def\midrule{\DoneWithHeader\noexpand\OldMidRule}

\newcolumntype{R}{>{\collectcell\FactorCell}r<{\endcollectcell}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rrrr}
    \toprule
              & A     & B     & C \\
    \midrule
        1     & 33 122   & 133   & 156 \\
        2     & 66 112   & 135   & 155 \\
        3     & 77 150   & 139   & 158 \\
        4     & 55 145   & 135   & 159 \\
        5     & 44 150   & 130   & 200 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\hspace{2.0ex}
\begin{tabular}{rrRR}
    \toprule
              & A     & B     & C \\
    \midrule
        1     & 33 122   & 133   & 156 \\
        2     & 66 112   & 135   & 155 \\
        3     & 77 150   & 139   & 158 \\
        4     & 55 145   & 135   & 159 \\
        5     & 44 150   & 130   & 200 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\end{document}
```