# Create LaTeX tables from plain numerical data?

Tags: tables

I have a bunch of MATLAB results like this

```
                   0  -2.000000000000000   2.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000  -1.926829268292683   3.707317073170731
   2.000000000000000   0.716910656478955  -6.475399900458298
   3.000000000000000   0.718921416773616   0.516843960338833
```

Here leftmost column is always 0,1,2,3,... so I have to get rid of those trailing zeros or to do row-numbering in LaTeX somehow.

However I want to convert all of them results to something like
[image: Table]

But anything simple and informative would do. I generated the table above using MathType editor, so I'm not even sure what some of those commands mean

```
\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
i&\vline& {{x_i}}&{{y_i}}\\
\hline
0&\vline& {{\rm{ - 2}}{\rm{.000000000000000}}}&{{\rm{2}}{\rm{.000000000000000}}}\\
1&\vline& {{\rm{ - 1}}{\rm{.926829268292683}}}&{{\rm{3}}{\rm{.707317073170731}}}\\
2&\vline& {{\rm{0}}{\rm{.716910656478955}}}&{{\rm{ - 6}}{\rm{.475399900458298}}}\\
3&\vline& {{\rm{0}}{\rm{.718921416773616}}}&{{\rm{0}}{\rm{.516843960338833}}}
\end{array}
```

What would you suggest?

Comment: Related Question: [Divide table cells by a certain amount](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65302/divide-table-cells-by-a-certain-amount/).  I would use the `collcell` pacakge so that the first column was truncated to an integer value, and simply `r` align the other two columns.

Comment: Do not use “MathType editor” again. Its output uses wrong syntax (`\rm` is an argument-less switch not a one-argument-taking macro) and deprecated commands (again: `\rm` is _old_). You could typeset numbers very comfortable with `siunitx` (in addition to `datatool` and/or `pgfplotstable` (which also has the PGF math macros and a conditional to check whether a number is an integer)). `siunitx` has the `zero-decimal-to-integer` option.

Comment: Probably an easy way might be to export the data to csv and use the excel converter plugin.

Answer (score 14):

If you are more or less in a hurry and do not want to delve too much into the works of `datatools` and/or `pgfplotstable` and your data is final, I would use the raw data and construct the `tabular` (with `siunitx`’ `S` column) manually.

With a decent editor you can [column-select](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_selection) the space between your numbers and simply add `&` and `\\` where needed.

The `siunitx` setup is pretty easy:

- `table-format`: specifies numbers of integer digits, decimal digits, …
- `table-auto-round`: rounds the input number according to `table-format`
- `zero-decimal-to-integer`: formats any trailing `.0000…` to a integer number

  (This is actually not needed as we already set the format for the first column to zero decimals and use the `table-auto-round` mode.)

In the example I set the `x_i` column to round at the fifth decimal, the `y_i` prints the decimals as they are, the rounding option has to be set off/false, because the number is too big for TeX.

I also used the [`booktabs`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package for nice tables but if you having other `tabular`s already in your document stay consistent!

Note that I have used a `tabular` not an `array` (math-mode). You need to add the `table` float environment and a table caption yourself (as usual).

The columns’ headers have to be hidden from the `siunitx` parser with a set of `{ }` braces.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs}
\sisetup{
    table-auto-round
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{S[table-format=1.0]S[table-format=-1.5]S[table-format=-1.15,table-auto-round=false]}
    \toprule
    {$i$}             & {$x_i$}            & {$y_i$}            \\ \midrule
    0                 & -2.000000000000000 & 2.000000000000000  \\
    1.000000000000000 & -1.926829268292683 & 3.707317073170731  \\
    2.000000000000000 & 0.716910656478955  & -6.475399900458298 \\
    3.000000000000000 & 0.718921416773616  & 0.516843960338833  \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Thanks man. It looks much better than what I came up with. I just added group-digits=false and it's good to go

Comment: Thanks once again! And sorry I edited out the original comment question (I found an answer before seeing your response)

Answer (score 14):

`pgfplotstable`'s syntax takes a bit of getting used to, but then it can really speed up your work, especially because it can read data files straight from the file system. Here's an example using your data:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable, booktabs}
\begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{ % Read the data into a macro we call \datatable
                   0  -2.000000000000000   2.000000000000000
   1.000000000000000  -1.926829268292683   3.707317073170731
   2.000000000000000   0.716910656478955  -6.475399900458298
   3.000000000000000   0.718921416773616   0.516843960338833
}\datatable
% If your data is in a file called data.csv, you could also just do:
%\pgfplotstableread{data.csv}\datatable

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    columns/0/.style={column name={$i$}}, % Set the name to be used for the first column
    columns/1/.style={
        column name=$x_i$,  % ... and the second
        dec sep align,      % align on the decimal marker
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,  % print trailing zeros
        /pgf/number format/precision=14     % print 14 digits
    },
    columns/2/.style={
        column name=$y_i$,
        dec sep align,
        /pgf/number format/fixed zerofill,
        /pgf/number format/precision=14
    },
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,    % booktabs rules
        after row=\midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    }]{\datatable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [pgfplotstable](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplotstable) package. It will let you read in datafiles and is able to output the data in many ways. Have a look through the manual. There are many examples for you to try.

Another option is the [datatool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) package.

Comment: I don't want to be rude, but maybe you can give any working example for my data in the original post? My job has to be finished in the morning and it's almost 1AM in my country. I am looking at the documentation, but without prior knowledge it might be too hard in this situation.