# What is wrong with this TeX macro

Tags: macros, tex-core, pgfplotstable

Still soldiering on with trying to learn these macros. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

The macro `\mycline{n-n}` is supposed to expand to `\cmidrule{1-1} ... \cmidrule{n-n}`, but in my code below I get multiple errors..

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\def\mycline(#1-#2){
  \xdef\MC{}%
  \foreach \a in {#1,...,#2}{%
  \toks0=\expandafter{\MC}%
  \def\temp{\cmidrule\expandafter{\a\expandafter-\a}}%
  \xdef\MC{\the\toks0 \temp}%
  }
  \MC
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
1&2&3&4\\ \mycline{1-3}
5&6&7&8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: There are various things up here, but before tackling them what is wrong with simply `\cmidrule{1-3}`?

Comment: hi @JosephWright as per egreg's answer I'm looking for a shortened \cmidrule. As a newbie I've been using \setlength{\extracolsep} to get the intercolumn gaps.

Comment: Related Question: [Wrapping \cmidrule in a macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63355/wrapping-cmidrule-in-a-macro).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As Joseph comments, there's no point in saying

```
\cmidrule{1-1}\cmidrule{2-2}\cmidrule{3-3}
```

because the effect is the same as saying

```
\cmidrule{1-3}
```

If you want to use the "shortening" feature of `\cmidrule` and generate

```
\cmidrule(lr){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-3}
```

then you can do the computations in a `\noalign` and then deliver the result:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\makeatletter
\def\mycline(#1-#2){\noalign{
  \gdef\@mycline{}%
  \foreach \a in {#1,...,#2}{%
    \edef\@tempa{\noexpand\cmidrule(lr){\a-\a}}%
    \expandafter\g@addto@macro\expandafter\@mycline\expandafter{\@tempa}%
  }}
  \@mycline
}


% the macro
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{llll}
1&2&3&4\\ \mycline(1-3)
5&6&7&8\\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice some points:

1. You have to say `\noexpand\cmidrule` in the `\edef`
2. Using `\g@addto@macro` is a more economic way to add tokens to a parameterless macro
3. Using a `@`-command such as `\@mycline` is better than `\MC` that could clobber some already existing macro
4. Using `\noalign` ensures that the work is done "outside any alignment cell"

Answer (score 16):

After `\\` (which expands amongst other things to the primitive `\cr` that ends a table row, TeX looks ahead *using expansion only* to see if the table cell needs special treatment, specifically it looks for `\noalign` `\span` or `omit`. As soon as it finds a non-expandable token that is not one of these it stops and processes the cell normally.

so if you put `\mycline` at the start of a row it is expanded one level and then the next token that is seen is the `\xdef` which is not expandable so after that it is not possible to have any spanning entries (which are needed for `\cline` `\cmidrule` `\multicolumn` and other similar constructs).

If you look how these things are coded in table packages you will see that either they have to work purely by expansion (so no `\xdef` or `foreach` etc) or they have to start a `\noalign`, do all the computation in the local scope of `\noalign` and then globally insert the expandable commands to span the columns after the `\noalign` has finished.