# Shift \cmidrule always by one column to the right

Tags: tables, booktabs

For weird [reasons](http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1354789-esttab-span-and-the-additional-column-introduced-by-labcol2), my tables (as produced by my statistics software, Stata) have `\cmidrule{3-6}` whenever they should have `\cmidrule{4-7}`. In my statistics software I can change the cmidrule, by I can not change th span it produces.

As a fix I want to define a new command `\cmidruleshiftedbyone` which autimatically adds 1 to the start and the end of the span and passes this on to `\cmidrule`.

I don't understand how the arguments for `\cmidrule`can be parsed and changed, otherwise I'd like to do something like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
%I know this wont work, I just have this to illustrate what I am trying to do:
\usepackage{calc}
\newcommand{\cmidruleshiftedbyone}[1]{\cmidrule{{#1}+{1-1}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\cmidruleshiftedbyone(lr){1-2} %I wan this to actually span 2-3
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcommand{\cmidruleshiftedbyone}[1]{\cmidrulehelp#1\relax}
\def\cmidrulehelp#1-#2\relax{\cmidrule{\numexpr#1+1\relax-\numexpr#2+1\relax}}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tabular}{ccc}
    1 & 2 & 3 \\\cmidruleshiftedbyone{1-2} %I wan this to actually span 2-3
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, except, when I have two cmidrules in one row, they are not vertically aligned. I assume this is an easy fix to, but weren't able to find it so far:   `\begin{tabular}{cccc}`

`1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\\cmidruleshiftedbyone{1-2}\cmidruleshiftedbyone{3-3}`

`\end{tabular}`

Comment: @sheß The problem is most strange.  It appears even if, for example, `\newcommand\cmidruleshiftedbyone[1]{\cmidrule{#1}}`.  I still do not have a fix.

Comment: I know, I also tried reducing the code further to figure out where it "begins", but I can't seem to make sense of it. Maybe this itself should become its own questions.

Comment: @sheß I think it could be a good question.

Comment: Turns out someone else had that question earlier: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63355/wrapping-cmidrule-in-a-macro, yet that answer is beyond me

Comment: For me the, the problem is solved, as an update of the Statistics-software allowed me to solve the issue one step before this.