# Framed box with only bottom rules and multiple lines inside a table cell

Tags: tables, parbox

I want to have a table with cells which have multiple lines and bottom rules.

I've tried

```
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

Title & \parbox{18em}{\centering A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
SubTitle & \parbox{18em}{\centering A not that long title}\\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
\end{tabular}
```

which seems to work fine. But the second `cmidrule` is a little bit far away from the text.

My first attempt begins with

```
\uline\makebox[18em][c]{A very very very very very very very very very very very \\ very very very very long title}
```

but apparently it doesn't support breaking lines inside the box.

I also tried `\parbox` with `\ul` (in the soul package) but error throws.

I think the closest approach is combine `\framebox` with `\parbox` but I don't know how to have the bottom rule only.

Comment: BTW, I also tried make a `tcolorbox` inside a cell but its nearby cell seems not vertically centered with that cell...

Comment: What is the reason for using parbox? Wouldn't a p type column be sufficient in order to allow for linebreaks in table cells?

Comment: @leandriis I wanna have a bottom rule of a fixed length. p works fine but I cannot have a single bottom rule only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package [`fbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fbox) provides and optional command to `fbox` where you decide which sides of surrounding box are drawn.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{fbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{18em}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
Title & \fbox[b]{\parbox[t]{18em}{A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title}}\\
SubTitle & \fbox[b]{A not that long title}\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this is what you want to achieve, but `\cmidrule` can be shortened of a desired amount, see: [How to make a \cline or \cmidrule narrower?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18691/how-to-make-a-cline-or-cmidrule-narrower)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{18em}}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
Title & A very very very very very very very very very very very very very very very long title\\\cmidrule(lr){2-2}
SubTitle & A not that long title\\\cmidrule(l{4.5em}r{4.5em}){2-2}
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]