# cmidrule overlap

Tags: tables, booktabs

I notice when I have a `\cdmidrule` command on neighboring columns

```
\cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8}
```

that it produces a single straight line between columns 5 and 8. Whereas what I want (for visual clarity) is a line between 5,6 a short gap and then a new line between 7-8.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try `\cmdrule(r{some length}){5-6}\cmidrule(l{some length}){7-8}`: it trims both rules on their common side (the trimming value can be adjusted).

Comment: Related (possible duplicate): [How to make a \cline or \cmidrule narrower?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/18691/134144)